# How to use variables assigned to a image in javascript and display them in html using a switch statement?

Tags: javascript

The purpose of this program is to display pictures of digital numbers in the form of a digital clock.  I am trying to check the count of the variable `s` and then use the resulting Element Id that is produced in the switch statement to display the proper picture.  But this code does not seem to work.  First experience with javascript, please be gentle.

```
function startTime(){
    var today=new Date();
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();

    m=checkTime(m);
    s=checkTime(s);
    showClockSeconds(s);
    t=setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function showClockSeconds(s){

    var Zero = document.createElement("img"); 
    Zero.setAttribute("src","http://i1363.photobucket.com/albums/r703/franco_fantillo/Zero_zpsd7f11364.jpg");
    Zero.setAttribute("alt" ,"No Image"); 

    var One = document.createElement("img"); 
    One.setAttribute("src","http://i1363.photobucket.com/albums/r703/franco_fantillo/Zero_zpsd7f11364.jpg");
    One.setAttribute("alt" ,"No Image");

    switch(s)
    {
    case 0:
        document.getElementById('Seconds').append Child(Zero);
        break;

    case 1:
        document.getElementById('Seconds').append Child(One);
        break;
    }

}

function checkTime(i)
{
    if (i<10)
    {
        i="0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
</script>

...

<div id="Seconds"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append Child` should be `appendChild` a single word, e.g.

```
document.getElementById('Seconds').appendChild(Zero);
```

Comment: he also needs to empty the DIV first. Otherwise he'll end up with `01020304050607...`